# EF6 Code First Mapping where key name is different in DB

Tags: c#, entity-framework, configuration, ef-code-first

I am trying to do a "code first" EF model based off an existing db (which I recognize immediately is counter to the concept of an EF code-first approach), but I keep running into a problem, and the error message does not make sense to me, so I'm hoping for some insight.

My table is defined like so:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BackupLocales]
(
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [LocaleId] INT NOT NULL constraint fkBackupLocales_Locale references dbo.Locales(Id), 
    [BackupLocaleId] INT NOT NULL constraint fxBackupLocales_BackupLocale references dbo.Locales(Id), 
    [Weight] INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
)
go
create unique nonclustered index uxBackupLocales_Locale_Weight on dbo.BackupLocales(LocaleId, [Weight]);
```

In code, I wrote the following entity class:

```
public class BackupLocale
{
    [Key]
    [Column("Id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public int Weight { get; set; }

    [Column("LocaleId")]
    public int PrimaryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PrimaryId")]
    public virtual Locale Primary { get; set; }

    [Column("BackupLocaleId")]
    public int BackupId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BackupId")]
    public virtual Locale Backup { get; set; }
}
```

... which, as far as I can tell (based off of the samples and documentation I've read), look correct.  The only "weirdness", as far as I can see, is the fact that the column name for the `Primary` locale is different in the database; I wanted to make it more specific in code than it is in the table.

Naturally, this does not work when trying to load the entity model (or else why would I be asking a question? :) )

I get a rather long error message, but the heart of it would be this part:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error 
>   occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner 
>   exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid
>   column name 'LocaleId'.

The problem here is, if I were not using EF, a `SqlClient.SqlException` with the message "Invalid column name 'LocaleId'" would mean that the column literally did not exist in the SQL server... but that is definitely not the case here.  It does exist... so I'm not sure what's going on here.  The only thing I can figure is the fact that I am changing the name of the property is somehow screwing up the mapping, but of course it could be that I'm just doing something dumb.

Have I misunderstood how the attributes are supposed to work?  Have I configured this incorrectly?  Or am I trying to do something that is not supported in EF6?

Comment: Are you sure you want the property `PrimaryId` to have a column name of `LocaleId`?

Comment: have tried it with fluent api?

Comment: @Arashjo I have not tried with fluent api.  I'd prefer to use attributes if possible, but if the problem is using attributes, I'll certainly switch.

Comment: @DavidG I think naming it `LocaleId` in code would be unnecessarily confusing, but if I have to, I will change it.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs I don't know exactly this is going to solve your problem but I had kind of similar problem your are facing .I finally used fluent api .give it a try

Comment: can you intercept the sql query ? (https://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/ or linqPad)

Comment: Can you post your Locale entity?

Comment: I will post when i get back to my workstation.

Comment: It's weird, I have no error when I tried to run your code. I assume your Locale entity looks like: 
        [Key]
        [Column("PrimaryId")]
        public int LocalId { get; set; }
        public string MyLocale { get; set; }
Can you show us how you load your entity model too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this was a Visual Studio problem.  I closed the solution, exited VS, restarted VS, and loaded the project, and it started working.  :(